# iis url rewrite with query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

May i ask how do i rewrite url from

"https://hello.com/test/api/zoo/v1/animal?animal_record_no=20900016431"

to

"https://145.123.2.12:5000/api/zoo/v1/animal?animal_record_no=20900016431"

the query string "animal_record_no" is optional.

Basically i just want to remove the "test" from the url and change the ip address.

This is what i have now, but it does not forward the query string:

```
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^test/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://145.123.2.12:5000/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}/{R:4}" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

If i were to use redirect, i got a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently error

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">                     <match url=".*test/(.*)" />                        
<conditions>                         
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="iex.odp.gov.sg" />                    
</conditions>                   
<action type="Redirect" url="http://145.123.2.12:5000/{R:1}" />
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add URL Rewrite like below:

[image]

**We don’t need to add rules for the query string, we just need to enable "Append query string", IIS will help us rewrite query string.**

The configuration in web.config is as follows:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test">
                    <match url="(.*)(test)/(api)/(zoo)/(v1)/(animal)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://145.123.2.12:5000/{R:3}/{R:4}/{R:5}/{R:6}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

**If the two ULRs are not pointing to the same host, you also need to enable reverse proxy.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: many thanks Ding Peng. I have not tried this. Will get back should i need help. Let me mark it as an answer first :)